# Appending an instance of a class to a list makes a copy rather than a reference in Python

Tags: python, class, object, reference, instance

I have a `Person` class and a `Car` class. Each `Person` can have multiple `Car` objects and each `Car` can be shared by more than one `Person`. See the code below:

```
class Person:

    community = []

    def __init__(self, name, id):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id

        Person.community.append(self)
        self.my_cars = []
        self.add_cars()

    def add_cars(self):
        c = Car.get_current_cars()
        for i in range(len(c)):
            self.my_cars.append(c[i])  # This is not making a reference to Car but creating a new copy
```

When a `Person` is created the current `Car` instances are added to that `Person` object's `Car` list `my_car`.

**Note I am adding all `Car` objects in `Car` as per minimum reproducible code. In reality this is not necessary because `my_car` may contain a subset of the total instances and that is why I am using the append function.**

When a `Car` instance is created I am storing each `Car` in a list so this can be accessed by `Person` like below:

```
class Car:

    cars = []

    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model
        Car.cars.append(self)


    @classmethod
    def get_current_cars(cls):
        return cls.cars

    @classmethod
    def delete(cls, name):

        for i in range(len(cls.cars)):
            if cls.cars[i].model == name:
                del cls.cars[i]
                break
```

The problem arises when I want to delete a `Car`. If this happens I would like each `Person` object's `my_car` list to be updated and this is not happening. In other words using the append function is not creating a pointer to each `Car` instance but rather it seems it is creating a copy.

The code below is a simple example that shows this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    models = ["Toyota", "BMW", "Tesla", "Fiat"]

    AA = [Car(models[i]) for i in range(len(models))]

    x = Car.get_current_cars()

    A = Person("john", 0)
    B = Person("Liam", 1)

    print([A.my_cars[i].model for i in range(len(A.my_cars))])
    print([B.my_cars[i].model for i in range(len(B.my_cars))])


    Car.delete("Toyota")
    x = Car.get_current_cars()

    print([x[i].model for i in range(len(x))])


    print([A.my_cars[i].model for i in range(len(A.my_cars))])
    print([B.my_cars[i].model for i in range(len(B.my_cars))])
```

How can I obtain my the behavior I desire?

Comment: Have a look at [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: See my answer with test.

Comment: See my latest update

Answer (score 0):

`del` deletes that variable, not the underlying object. That object is deleted when its counter of references drops to 0 and garbage collector decides to delete it.

Imagine that every object has a counter. Let's say your cars are `list` objects (Only for the sake of simplicity. The concept is the same for every mutable object):

```
car1 = [1, 2, 3]
```

Here the counter for object `car1` points to is 1. Every time something points to that object, the counter goes up:

```
car2 = car1
car3 = car1
```

Now the counter is 3. When you delete a variable using `del` the reference goes down, but the object is only deleted when the counter drops to 0 and the garbage collector decides to delete that object:

```
del car2
```

The counter is 2 now and `car1` and `car3` are still pointing to it, trying to alter `car1` would alter `car3`:

```
car1.append(4)
print(car3)    # output: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Conclusion: When there is more than one reference to a mutable object, all of them can alter that object, but none can actually delete the object on its own.
When you collect those cars in a list, you still have a reference to those cars:

```
car4 = ["Toyota"]
car5 = ["Audi"]
car6 = ["Tesla"]

c = [car4, car5, car6]
my_cars = []
for x in c:
    my_cars.append(x)
```

Here `c` and `my_cars` both hold references to the same cars. They each point to a different `list` object, and each `list` object points to each `car` object on the behalf of its own. Each, increase the counter by one, thus the counter is increased by 2. You can alter cars using either of the lists:

```
c[0][0] = "Mercedes-Benz"
print(my_cars[0])  # output: ['Mercedes-Benz']
```

But as we concluded above, you cannot destroy the object using just one of the references:

```
del c[0]
print(my_cars)  # output is still [['Mercedes-Benz'], ['Audi'], ['Tesla']]. The object still exists.
```

On the other hand, when you ask  `c` and `my_cars` to point to the same list, they both point to that (one) `list` object. Note that there is just one `list` object, and any changes to that object affects both **variables**:

```
c = [car4, car5, car6]
my_cars = c

del c[0]
print(my_cars) # output: [['Mercedes-Benz'], ['Tesla']]. The first object is removed.
```

Note that, then the object might still not be deleted if some other variables are still pointing to it:

```
print(car4) # output: ['Mercedes-Benz']. car4 is still pointing to that car object, thus it is not destroyed.
```

But the single `list` object both `c` and `my_cars` are pointing to does not contain it anymore.

Comment: I am sure you are right. But then, how do you explain the fact that when instead of the for loop in the add_car() function I write  self.my_cars = c, then after the deletion the my_cars list gets updated for all persons...

Comment: @user7331538 I added more explanation *to the post*, let me know if it is still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

You have to rearrange the code somehow to `Person.my_cars` get the direct reference of `Car.cars` as you obviously intended. Doing so, when it `Car.cars`'s elements - and thus its bounds to their pointers -  has been deleted with `del` statement, it will be done with `Person.my_cars` referred elements too. 
When you use `list.append()` it will create a new variable and it assigns a pointer to the same address like the original - copied - variable.
`del` won't eliminate this new bound when you delete the original variable.

**Solution 1:**

So as a workaround this problem change add_cars method (at least append(), as you wrote this is just a minimal code):

```
def add_cars(self):
    self.my_cars = Car.get_current_cars() # you don't need any loop to copy all the cars from Car class's cars.
```

**Solution 2:**

You can delete the new bounds directly as well.

```
import weakref

class Person:

    community = []
    __refs__ = set()

    def __init__(self, name, id):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.__refs__.add(weakref.ref(self))

        Person.community.append(self)
        self.my_cars = []
        self.add_cars()

    def add_cars(self):
        c = Car.get_current_cars()
        for i in range(len(c)):
            self.my_cars.append(c[i])  # This is not making a reference to Car but creating a new copy

    @classmethod
    def get_instances(cls):
        for inst_ref in cls.__refs__:
            inst = inst_ref()
            if inst is not None:
                yield inst                   


class Car:

    cars = []

    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model
        Car.cars.append(self)

    @classmethod
    def get_current_cars(cls):
        return cls.cars

    @classmethod
    def delete(cls, name):

        for i in range(len(cls.cars)):
            if cls.cars[i].model == name:
                del cls.cars[i]
                for inst in Person.get_instances():
                    del inst.my_cars[i]                                
                break
```

**Test:**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    models = ["Toyota", "BMW", "Tesla", "Fiat"]

    AA = [Car(models[i]) for i in range(len(models))]

    x = Car.get_current_cars()

    A = Person("john", 0)
    B = Person("Liam", 1)

    print([A.my_cars[i].model for i in range(len(A.my_cars))])
    print([B.my_cars[i].model for i in range(len(B.my_cars))])


    Car.delete("Toyota")

    x = Car.get_current_cars()

    print([x[i].model for i in range(len(x))])


    print([A.my_cars[i].model for i in range(len(A.my_cars))])
    print([B.my_cars[i].model for i in range(len(B.my_cars))])
```

**Out:**

```
['Toyota', 'BMW', 'Tesla', 'Fiat']
['Toyota', 'BMW', 'Tesla', 'Fiat']
['BMW', 'Tesla', 'Fiat']
['BMW', 'Tesla', 'Fiat']
['BMW', 'Tesla', 'Fiat']
```

Comment: I don't fully understand this. If you can elaborate or re-word that would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Actually it would, since OP collects those instances to a list (`cars`) and alters those instances as needed. The problem is that deleting that reference to the  instances won't actually delete the objects.

Comment: @user7331538 I try

Comment: @user7331538 See the solution